# How to replace a string in a column based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['US123','1111'],\
                   ['CA456', '2222'],\
                   ['US123', '3333'],\
                   ['US123','4444'], \
                   ['CA456', '5555']], columns=['ID', 'Notes'])
df
```

[image]

The desired output is:

[image]

What is the best way to add string `; CA` to column `Notes` when the value in column `ID` starts with `CA`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), that'll change column `Notes` only where needed, based on the condition on the `ID` column

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.startswith('CA'), 'Notes'] = df['Notes'] + '; CA'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `str.extract`

```
df['Notes'] = (';'+df.ID.str.extract('(CA)')[0]).fillna('').radd(df.Notes)
df
Out[292]: 
      ID    Notes
0  US123     1111
1  CA456  2222;CA
2  US123     3333
3  US123     4444
4  CA456  5555;CA
```